# How would I design a TryParse method which provides detailed information in case of a parsing error?

Tags: c#, .net, api-design

When parsing user input, it is [generally recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4945763/87698) to not to throw and catch exceptions but rather to use validation methods. In the .NET BCL, this would be the difference between, for example, `int.Parse` (throws an exception on invalid data) and `int.TryParse` (returns `false` on invalid data).

I am designing my own

```
Foo.TryParse(string s, out Foo result)
```

method and I'm unsure about the return value. I could use `bool` like .NET's own `TryParse` method, but that would give no indication about the *type* of error, about the exact reason *why* `s` could not be parsed into a `Foo`. (For example, `s` could have unmatched parenthesis, or the wrong number of characters, or a `Bar` without a corresponding `Baz`, etc.)

As a *user* of APIs, I strongly dislike methods which just return a success/failure Boolean without telling me *why* the operation failed. This makes debugging a guessing game, and I don't want to impose that on my library's clients either.

I can think of a lot of workarounds to this issue (return status codes, return an error string, add an error string as an out parameter), but they all have their respective downsides, and I also want to *stay consistent with the conventions of the .NET Framework*.

Thus, my question is as follows:

**Are there methods in the .NET Framework which (a) parse input without throwing exceptions and (b) still return more detailed error information than a simple true/false Boolean?**

Comment: That link does not conclude it is not recommended to throw and catch exceptions.  There are times that the best way is to use `Parse()`.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the *monad* pattern for your return type.

`ParseResult<Foo> foo = FooParser.Parse("input");`

Note also, it should not be Foo's responsibility to figure out how it should be parsed from user input as this directly binds your domain layer to your UI layer, and also violates the single responsibility principal.

You can also make a parse result class specific to `Foo` instead of using generics, depending on your use case.

A foo specific parse result class might look something like this:

```
class FooParseResult
{
     Foo Value { get; set; }
     bool PassedRequirement1 { get; set; }
     bool PassedRequirement2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Monad version:

```
class ParseResult<T>
{
     T Value { get; set; }
     string ParseErrorMessage { get; set; }
     bool WasSuccessful { get; set; }
}
```

---

I am not aware of any methods in the .net framework that return detailed parse error information.

Comment: I understand your comment about UI layer binding, but in this case there exists a standardized, canonical string representation of Foo, so it makes sense to have `Foo.ToString` and `Foo.Parse`.

Comment: And, w.r.t. my bolded question, can you give me an example from the .NET BCL that uses this pattern?

Comment: How is that a monad?

Comment: @Heinzi: Any method that returns a `Func<T>` would meet that criteria, if you include in `T` the information you need.  Returning detailed error information is largely up to you.  Have you considered using a `Maybe<T>`?  See https://mikhail.io/2016/01/monads-explained-in-csharp/

Comment: @JacquesB: I was kinda wondering the same thing.  The method signature is compatible with modanic behavior, but that's about it.

Comment: I like this answer very much, but would not have a problem if there was a static method on Foo called "Parse(string fooString)" which returned a ParseResult<Foo>.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) in the MVC framework. It represent an attempted parse of some input and may have a collection of errors.

That said, I don't think there is a recurring pattern for this in the .net BCL, since exceptions is - for better or worse - the established pattern for reporting error conditions in .net. I think you should just go ahead and implement your own solution suiting your problem, for example a `ParseResult` class with two subclasses, `SuccessfulParse` and `FailedParse`, where `SuccessfulParse` has a property with the parsed value and `FailedParse` has an error message property. Combining this with pattern matching in C# 7 could be pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar problems with wanting to use a `TryParse/Convert/etc.` method where I *sometimes* need to know how and why it failed.

I ended up taking inspiration from how some serializers handle errors and using events.  This way the syntax for my `TryX(..., out T)` method looks as clean as any other and reliably returns a simple `false` as the pattern implies.

However, when I want need more details I just add an Event Handler and get whatever results I need in a package as complex or simple as I want (the `MyEventArgs` below).  Add it to a list of strings, add an `ExceptionDispatchInfo` and capture Exceptions; let the caller decide if and how it wants to deal with anything that goes wrong.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyConverter();

        //here's where I'm subscibing to errors that occur
        c.Error += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Details);

        c.TryCast<int>("5", out int i);
    }
}

//here's our converter class
public class MyConverter
{
    //invoke this event whenever something goes wrong and fill out your EventArgs with details
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Error;

    //intentionally stupid implementation
    public bool TryCast<T>(object input, out T output)
    {
        bool success = true;
        output = default (T);

        //try-catch here because it's an easy way to demonstrate my example
        try
        {
            output = (T)input;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            Error?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs{Details = ex.ToString()});
        }

        return success;
    }
}

//stores whatever information you want to make available
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Details {get; set;}
}
```